# Application crashes on element reader (pdftron)

Tags: c#, pdf, pdftron, pdfnet

I have an issue with pdftron, where opening a certain file, will cause our application to crash with following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'pdftron.Common.PDFNetException' occurred in PDFNet.dll

Additional information: Exception: 

 Message: Missing resource

 Conditional expression: res

 Filename   : ContentResources.hpp

 Function   : trn::PDF::ContentResources::GetResource

 Linenumber : 26
```

In our code: it's in the following line that the error occurs:

```
while ((element = elReader.Next()) != null)
```

When doing try/catch, we see that the only thing missing from the page is the text that's written diagonally on that page. Does this have anything to do with a missing font maybe ? Don't mind the cursor in the picture, it doesn't know where to go with the text missing.

[image]

I can send the pdf file on request.

[PDF File](https://www.docdroid.net/7ySeCKi/super-max-5-wb-00-p1-2.pdf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not on the latest version of PDFNet, 6.7.1, then I would first try against that, as the issue might have been resolved already.

Otherwise, since the issue is document specific, you would need to provide that, by either sharing here, or sending to [pdftron support](https://www.pdftron.com/support/reportproblem.html).

Comment: I added a PDF file link in my question. We aren't on the latest version, I talked to my senior and apparently there were some issues with other components of the application when updating to the latest SDK, hence we're still on 6.6.1.

Comment: If you had any issues migrating to 6.7.1, please report here: https://www.pdftron.com/support/reportproblem.html

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce an error. At the very least, you can download the latest SDK, and run your file through one of the samples, such as ElementReader sample. I think it will not happen, which means you need to update. If it does, then please post all the pertinent details.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out on tuesday, when I'm back in. If that's the case we'll fix it when we update to the latest SDK.